# Less-than function dereferencing pointers

Tags: c++

There are cases where one has pointers in an STL container and where less-than comparison shall not be made by pointer but by the objects pointed to. A simple example would be a vector which shall be sorted by the real numbers. Currently I solve this with:

```
template<class T_PTR> struct ltDeref
{
    bool operator()(T_PTR p0,T_PTR p1) const {return *p0<*p1;}
};
```

and use it as

```
vector<double*> vIn;
sort(vIn.begin(),vIn.end(),ltDeref<double*>());
```

or

```
set<double*,ltDeref<double*> > someSet;
```

Instead of writing my own comparison function, is there a more "standard" way in C++ which doesn't require a user made template?

Comment: why set<double*>` in set instead of just `set<double>` ?

Comment: There are cases where one has **pointers to pointers** in an STL container. Shouldn't there be a standard solution in C++ which doesn't require a user made template? There are cases where one has [**pointers to pointers to pointers**](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) ...

Comment: @billz This is a simple example to reduce the question to the minimum. You can replace double* by a pointer to some fat object that was created on the heap.

Comment: How should STL know how to implement compare operation from UDT?

Comment: @Praetorian Sure, but pointers in a container are an every-day thing while pointers to pointers are in most cases just a habit of people who programmed plain C before. Therefore I assumed that there is some feature in the language to dereference the first layer.

Comment: Currently your question is answered with `yes/no`. What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @billz It would use operator<() of the dereferenced object.

Comment: @Default If there is no standard solution, its fine. But if there is one, my template would re-invent the wheel which would not be a good programming style.

Comment: I took the liberty to change the phrasing of the question in your question. If you'd like it is possible to roll it back via the `edit` button (or edit it further).

Comment: Writing your own, generic solution for a specific situation that you find yourself in *is* "standard" C++, in the sense that that's idiomatic. C++ is a language for library-writing.

Comment: Thanks to all. I just needed to get sure that my template solution is no redundant code.

Answer (score 1):

Often you can use [the functors available in `functional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) to construct a resulting sort functor purely from standard constructions.

But there is none to dereference a pointer `T*` so, you'll have to use your own comparator.

---

The closest you can get is when your "pointer type" is not a primitive, but some User-Defined-Type with an `operator*` that can be addressed.

The following code is C++11 (for the use of `std::bind` which is simpler than `std::bind1st` and `std::bind2nd`).

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// Fakes a "smart pointer" wrapper around data
template <typename T>
struct Ptr
{
    Ptr(T data) : data(data) {};
    const T& operator*() const { return data; }

private:
    T data;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Ptr<double>> vIn;
    vIn.push_back(Ptr<double>(5));
    vIn.push_back(Ptr<double>(2));
    vIn.push_back(Ptr<double>(6));

    using namespace std::placeholders;
    std::sort(
        vIn.begin(),
        vIn.end(),
        std::bind(
            std::less<double>(),
            std::bind(&Ptr<double>::operator*, _1),
            std::bind(&Ptr<double>::operator*, _2)
        )
    );

    std::vector<Ptr<double>>::const_iterator it = vIn.begin(), end = vIn.end();
    for ( ; it != end; ++it)
        std::cout << ',' << **it;
}
```

- [Output](https://ideone.com/dPztYr): ,2,5,6

As such, if instead of `double*` you have `std::unique_ptr<double>` or `std::shared_ptr<double>`, then this could work:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef std::unique_ptr<double> STDUPD;

    std::vector<STDUPD> vIn;
    vIn.push_back(STDUPD(new double(5)));
    vIn.push_back(STDUPD(new double(2)));
    vIn.push_back(STDUPD(new double(6)));

    using namespace std::placeholders;
    std::sort(
        vIn.begin(),
        vIn.end(),
        std::bind(
            std::less<double>(),
            std::bind(&STDUPD::operator*, _1),
            std::bind(&STDUPD::operator*, _2)
        )
    );

    std::vector<STDUPD>::const_iterator it = vIn.begin(), end = vIn.end();
    for ( ; it != end; ++it)
        std::cout << ',' << **it;
}
```

- [Same output](https://ideone.com/ZAoTle)

Yet another reason to avoid "raw" pointers if you can...

Comment: it is easier to use lambda instead of bind here: `[](double* a, double* b) {return *a < *b;}`

Comment: @Simon: Except the point was to use existing standard constructs. :) Yours is a perfectly valid example but I was trying to do it without writing "new" types, per se.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready-made solution as other answers say.  A raw-pointer dereferencing comparator could be improved slightly by making it only available for raw-pointer types with the following explicit template specialisation.  I expect this would give slightly better error messages from the compiler in the event that a non-pointer type is used.

```
template<class T>
struct PointeeLess;

template<class T>
struct PointeeLess<T const *>
{
    bool operator()( T const * a , T const * b ) const { return *a < *b; }
};
```

OTOH, the template in the question will work for non raw-pointer types that implement operator*.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing in STL but could not find it.
Ended up writing my own (handles NULL)

```
class DeRefPtrLess {

public:

template<typename T>
    bool operator()(const T *l, const T *r) const {
        if (l == NULL
                && r == NULL) {
            return false;
        }
        if (l == NULL) {
            return true;
        }

        return *l < *r;
    }
```

};